# Import css files in typescript-files using aliases, webpack

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, loader, css-loader

i set up a project using webpack, react and typescript. I am now trying to use aliases for imports, which works fine for the most part.
However, i can't make importing css files to work with aliases.

I added the following part to my `webpack.config.json`

```
...
    resolve: {
        extensions: ["", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json", "css", ".scss"],
        alias: {
            BaseComponents: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "BaseComponents"),
            Pages: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "Pages"),
            Styles: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "Styles"),
        },
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.(css)$/,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
            },
        ],
    },

...
```

and the following part to the `tsconfig.json`

```
...
    "paths": {
            "BaseComponents/*": ["./src/BaseComponents/*"],
            "Pages/*": ["./src/Pages/*"],
            "Styles/*": ["./src/Styles/*"],
     },
...
```

Importing other react components and normal functions works as expected.

When i write

```
import "../Styles/test.css";
```

it works fine. But using the alias

```
import "Styles/test.css";
```

doesn't work, even though the ide doesn't complain and intellisense works when typing in the path.

The error is
`ERROR in ./src/BaseComponents/App.tsx 3:0-25 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'Styles/test.css'`

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup, had the same issue when I was trying to build the project but everything worked fine in the IDE, etc. I was able to solve it by installing `babel-plugin-module-resolver` and configure it as following:

```
"plugins": [
  ...,
  [
    "module-resolver",
    {
      "alias": {
        "@components": "./src/components"
      }
    }
  ]
]
```